# Bounding norm of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, tensor-products, positive-semidefinite

> The problem

Consider two $d$-dimensional POVMs, $ \mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$, given by POVM elements $\left\{E_{1}, \ldots E_{n}\right\}$ and $\left\{F_{1}, \ldots F_{n}\right\}$, respectively.
(a POVM is a set of positive semi-definite Hermitian matrices $\{G_{i}\}$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal {H}$ that sum to the identity matrix, ${\displaystyle \sum _{i=1}^{n}G_{i}=\operatorname {I} .}$)

Suppose that for some state $|\psi\rangle \in \mathbb{C}^{d} \otimes \mathbb{C}^{d}$ we have that
$$
\left\langle\psi\left|\left(E_{i} \otimes F_{j}\right)\right| \psi\right\rangle \leq \epsilon
$$
for all distinct $i, j \in\{1, \ldots, n\}$, where $\epsilon<1$. Upper bound, as tightly as you can, the 2-norm
$$
\|\left(E_{i} \otimes I_{d}\right)|\psi\rangle-\left(I_{d} \otimes F_{i}\right)|\psi\rangle \|
$$
in terms of $\epsilon$.

> My attempt

For distinct $i,j$, we have
$$
\label{bound}
\left\langle\psi\left|\left(E_{i} \otimes F_{j}\right)\right| \psi\right\rangle \leq \epsilon.
$$
As $i,j$ runs from $1$ to $n$ we have $n^2-n$ choices of distinct $i,j$. Summing them up
$$
    \sum^n_{i,j;i\neq j}\left\langle\psi\left|\left(E_{i} \otimes F_{j}\right)\right| \psi\right\rangle \leq \left(n^2-n\right)\epsilon.
$$
Since the total probability over all choices of $i,j$ is $1$, we have the following lower bound on the total probability when $i=j$,

\begin{equation}
    \sum^n_i\left\langle\psi\left|\left(E_{i} \otimes F_{i}\right)\right| \psi\right\rangle\geq 1-\left(n^2-n\right)\epsilon.
\end{equation}

We need to upper bound
$$
\|\left(E_{i} \otimes I_{d}\right)|\psi\rangle-\left(I_{d} \otimes F_{i}\right)|\psi\rangle \|
$$
Taking square,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\|\left(E_{i} \otimes I_{d}\right)|\psi\rangle-\left(I_{d} \otimes F_{i}\right)|\psi\rangle \|^2&=&\|\left(E_{i} \otimes I_{d}\right)|\psi\rangle\|^2-2\langle\psi|E_i\otimes F_i|\psi\rangle+\|\left(F_{i} \otimes I_{d}\right)|\psi\rangle\|^2\\
&\leq& 2-2\langle\psi|E_i\otimes F_i|\psi\rangle
\end{eqnarray*}
Summing over all $i$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum^n_i\|\left(E_{i} \otimes I_{d}\right)|\psi\rangle-\left(I_{d} \otimes F_{i}\right)|\psi\rangle \|^2&\leq&2n-2\sum^n_i\langle\psi|E_i\otimes F_i|\psi\rangle
\end{eqnarray*}
Substituting for $\sum^n_i\left\langle\psi\left|\left(E_{i} \otimes F_{i}\right)\right| \psi\right\rangle$ from above, we get,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum^n_i\|\left(E_{i} \otimes I_{d}\right)|\psi\rangle-\left(I_{d} \otimes F_{i}\right)|\psi\rangle \|^2&\leq&2n-2 \left(1-\left(n^2-n\right)\epsilon\right)\\
&\leq&2\left(n^2-1\right)\epsilon
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, we get our upper bound as,
$$ 
\|\left(E_{i} \otimes I_{d}\right)|\psi\rangle-\left(I_{d} \otimes F_{i}\right)|\psi\rangle \|\leq \sqrt{\sum^n_i\|\left(E_{i} \otimes I_{d}\right)|\psi\rangle-\left(I_{d} \otimes F_{i}\right)|\psi\rangle \|^2}\leq\sqrt{2\left(n^2-1\right)\epsilon}
$$

Is this correct? Does a better solution exist?

Comment: Please avoid the use of acronyms for clarity. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: @KBS In case you were wondering, POVM = "positive operator valued measure"